# How can I save a video file from url with a function in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to download one or many videos in download folder with a function, how can I do that with a function with Angular? Do I have to convert the url into a blob?

I have an array like this:

```
videos:[
    {
        selected: true,
        url:'https://13-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/2113/3/85569724/224036863.mp4?expires=1500882066&token=0369919720650b346b338',
        description:'video1'
    }, 
    {
        selected: false, 
        url:'https://13-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/2113/3/85569724/224036863.mp4?expires=1500882066&token=0369919720650b346b338', 
        description:'video2'
    }
]
```

I want to download just the selected videos, maybe it could be with a service?

Comment: IMO, it depends on backend also. Your question is how to download videos or how to download only selected videos  ?

Comment: I want to do this in front, I want to know how download videos

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript library; It does'nt matter whether you use angular or not:

https://github.com/PixelsCommander/Download-File-JS/